# How to extract token string from Bearer token? i need this method befor @UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard) in nest ? i use nextjs for front

Tags: authentication, next.js, jwt, nestjs

I use the fetch method in Nextjs

```
async function fetchProfile() {
    const res = await fetch(`http://localhost:5000/api/v1/users/1`, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "token": "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token")
      }
    })
}
```

this is my controller

```
@UseGuards(JwtAuthGuard)
  @Get(':id')
  findOne(@Param('id', ParseIntPipe) params: { id: number }, @Req() req) {
    console.log(req);
    return this.userService.findOne(params.id, req);
  }
```

if I comment first line give the console log with a token like

```
token: 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJpZCI6IjEiLCJlbWFpbCI6ImF6YWQuaG9zc2VpbjIzQGdtYWlsLmNvbSIsImlhdCI6MTY5MDA5NzE4OX0._ncc6g71l8mrmgNTUUybhPRG696tX8sE3GAL-Fs_Kzo',
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it from your strategy:

```
export class JwtAppStrategy extends PassportStrategy(Strategy, 'strategy-name') {
  constructor(private config: ConfigService, private userService: UserService) {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(), // extract from header
      secretOrKey: 'secret',
    });
  }

  async validate(payload: { id: number }) {
    // custom logic
    return true;
  }
}
```

Comment: this is my constructor   ...constructor() {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromExtractors([
        JwtStrategy.extractJWT,
        ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ]),
      // passReqToCallback: true,
      secretOrKey: jwtSecret,
    });
  }

Comment: ExtractJwt.fromExtractors will try to extract from multiple places until it finds the token in the order you give. We need to know whether your token is in headers or request body to extract it correctly.

Comment: tnx your answer is not good but  show me the way

Answer (score 0):

I use this strategy and work perfectly

```
constructor() {
    super({
      jwtFromRequest: ExtractJwt.fromExtractors([
        JwtStrategy.extractJWT,
        ExtractJwt.fromAuthHeaderAsBearerToken(),
      ]),
      // passReqToCallback: true,
      secretOrKey: jwtSecret,
    });
  }

  private static extractJWT(req: Request): string | null {
    if (req.cookies && 'token' in req.headers) {    
      return JwtStrategy.extractToken(req);
    }
    return null;
  }

  private static extractToken(req) {
    if (req.headers.token && req.headers.token.split(' ')[0] === 'Bearer') {
      return req.headers.token.split(' ')[1];
    } else if (req.query && req.query.token) {
      return req.query.token;
    }
    return null;
  }
```